# How to get value from canvas using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, canvas, selenium-webdriver, getvalue

I want to check whether the balance amount is correctly deducted from the bet amount using selenium webdriver.

Game is in canvas, so how can I get the value from canvas.

Below is my canvas code:

```
<canvas 
    width="3123" 
    height="736" 
    style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 3123px;height: 736px;">
</canvas>
```